# So i'm using Javascript const keyword, what happens in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, constants, ecmascript-5

I understand that the const keyword has been already implemented across the board in browsers except for IE10 versions, but is it viable? If someone jumps on my site on IE10< will the "const" keyword be re-assigned to "var"? if not will the whole site fail? the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) docs on the const keyword give a handy chart at the bottom which tells me that not only IE, but rather many Mobile browsers do not support it either. should i just scrap it and use var?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/5-ways-to-test-your-website-in-old-versions-of-ie/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take Babel, the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) to ECMAScript 5 transpiler.

If you write:

```
const a = 123;
```

It outputs:

```
"use strict";

var a = 123;
```

If the potential of breaking your code on unsupported browsers isn't enough, i think that should be.

Comment: what is the viability of this issue being fixed by using an es5-shim?

Comment: That won't work, es5-shim is basically a sum of a lot of polyfills to use es5 in es3, but it doesn't transpile code, and that's what you need in order to make const work. Either use var, or move on to es6 with Babel

Answer (score 9):

IE11 and above supports `const` but IE10 and below do not.

If you attempt to use `const` in any browser that does not support it, you will get a syntax error. If you must support older browsers, you cannot use `const` unless you use a transpiler to compile your code down into ES5. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is a good example of such a transpiler.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, are you sure you aren't referring to `let` (https://caniuse.com/#feat=let)? If `const` has an issue as well, could you provide a source? `const` is fully supported in IE11 according to https://caniuse.com/#feat=const.

Comment: @MuffinTheMan `const` is only partially supported according to your source.

Comment: @bfontaine wow, good call! I wonder if that page was updated at some point, or if I was completely blind when reading it a year ago?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write clean ES6 (ES2015) code using `const` you could use JS compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). For example:

```
const a = 1;
```

it recompile to

```
"use strict";
var a = 1;
```

If you want painless babel configuration use this [yeoman babel generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-babel).

Comment: what is the viability of this issue being fixed by using an es5-shim?